# how can i track last 5 pages visited using cookies in php

Tags: php, cookies

```
  <?php

   session_start();
   if(empty($_SESSION['track']))
       $_SESSION['history'] = array($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
   else {
       $_SESSION['track'][] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
   if(count($_SESSION['track']) > 5)
       array_shift($_SESSION['track']);
   }

   function display()
   {
       print_r(array_values($_SESSION['track']));
   }
  ?>
```

i was able to do it using session but i need to use only cookies and php to track the last 5 pages visited.
any idea guys??

Any comment or answer will appreciate. Thanking in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? (the example you've shown us does not address your requirement to store the data in cookies)

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = unserialize($_COOKIE['history']);
array_push($url,your_url);
setcookie('history', serialize($url));
```

onload of every page first retrieve the value of cookie in url and push the current url in it and add set it to cookie